# It there a way to access an object property while the object is in JSON format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JS and have been trying to understand how objects work.

```
var string = JSON.stringify({name: "X", born: 1980});
console.log(string);
// → {"name":"X","born":1980}
```

Out of curiosity, I have tried the following methods to try and access the property "born" while the object is in the JSON format.

```
console.log(string["born"]);
// → undefined
```

I guess this doesn't work because even if the variable string is in Javascript object format {name:"X",born:1980}, to call for 1980, it would require the same expression console.log(string["born"]).

```
console.log(string[""born""]);
// → Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 

console.log(string["\"born\""]);
// → Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I have a feeling these are just codes which experienced programmers would say make absolutely no sense at all. But I wanted to try them out to see for myself nonetheless.

Is there any way to access an object property while the object is in JSON format, besides using JSON.parse on the variable string? Also, can someone please help explain why the different ways I've tried returned either undefined or error? That would be very helpful for my understanding.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access the properties as your "object" is not internally stored or represented the way you're expecting.

`JSON.stringify()` returns an object of type **[String](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)** which offers you the properties and methods described in the documentation.

If you want  to "access" your property you can of course use `split()` or `indexOf()` to modify your string and get the value but this may be a tricky and hard way.

I see no reason for not using `JSON.parse()` access your object the way it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Do not stringify the javascript object.
If you stringify, you assign a string data type to the variable named string. There are 2 ways of accessing properties of JSON objects.

1. Dot notation

   var obj = { name:"X", born:1980}

   console.log(obj.name);

   console.log(obj.born);
2. Bracket notation

   var obj = { name:"X", born:1980 }

   console.log(obj["name"]);

   console.log(obj["born"]);

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable **string** doesn't have **born**-property. You had an object and you convert it to string, if you want to get property from object you have to use the object. f.e.

```
var obj = {name: "X", born: 1980};
console.log(obj.born); // also you can write obj["born"] if you want
var string = JSON.stringify(obj); // this string doesn't have property "born" it has the whole JSON of your object
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json back to an object, or if you know what the json contains, you can try with a RegExp:

```
var string = JSON.stringify({name: "X", born: 1980});
console.log(string)

//SOLUTION 1
var object = JSON.parse(string);
console.log('from parsed json ', object['born']);

//SOLUTION 2
//warning: this regexp is simple and will not work with any input
var match = string.match(/"born":\s*(true|false|null|\d+|"[^"]*")\s*[,}]/)
console.log('from regexp ', match[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qu9gxcyb/